# Android how to use webview with galleryview

Tags: android, scroll, webview, galleryview

I want to a galleryview what its' items as webview. So i am not wanting scrolling image, i want to scroll webviews.. Please help. I make some things but webview doesnt run correct into gallery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use custom Adapter for your gallery view and then override getView method. Something like this:

```
    public class CustomGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter
```

and then

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_WEBVIEW_LAYOUT, null);
        }
        // Here do some changes to webview view
        // view.SetXY()...

        return view;
    }
```

and configure your gallery view with new adapter:

```
    gallery.setAdapter(new CustomGalleryAdapter(...));
```

The `YOUR_WEBVIEW_LAYOUT` is a layout created in layout resources, which may contain also only a single webview.

Comment: i already use custom adapter and override getview but i can set textview and imageviews contents but webview doesnt show my content which set it.